# Bilinear Interpolation

Tags: mathematics

In the context of *bilinear interpolation*, if we look at the image below:

[image]

I'm confused about what `P` is exactly. I'm not sure if it's a point (as in (x, y)) or if it's a single value.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have taken the image on Wikipedia, on the [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) page. The legend of that image says

> [...] the green dot is the point at which we want to interpolate.

So the `P` is at first a `point` from which we want to find the `value`.

You submit a set of coordinates to the interpolation function (x, y), and it spits you a scalar (a single value).

Comment: Minor quibble: since interpolation is often done on multi-channel textures, the return value won't *always* be a scalar - it could be a full RGBA quartet for instance. This is still equivalent to bilinearly interpolating R, G, B, and A separately as individual scalars as you describe; I only mention it because users are also likely to encounter vector implementations which interpolate all components in one call.

Answer (score 1):

the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) where you probably get that image states : "The four red dots show the data points and the green dot is the point at which we want to interpolate."

So, you know the values at Q12,Q22,Q11,Q21 , and yoi want interpolate the value at point P